# ThemeRoller integration jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, themeroller

I cannot get jQuery UI to apply my theme downloaded from ThemeRoller. I think I have made some sort of error in the ordering of my calls to CSS and JS or else perhaps Bootstrap is interfering with my jQuery UI custom CSS. I have checked all the other questions regarding this problem and have made all appropriate changes, but still get the default theme. I have tried multiple themes as well, no dice.

Here is what is in my head tag

```
<!-- CSS -->        
    <!-- Fonts-->
<!--font needed for sun symbols-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/segoe-ui-symbol" type="text/css"/>

<!-- Google Font-->    
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   

<!--Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--Bootstrap-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- ThemeRoller: I get default UI styles with either this or below-->
<link href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- jQuery UI: -->
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">        

<!-- My CSS-->
<link href="css/cssGard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--SCRIPTS:--> 

<!-- jQuery-->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I tried moving the Scripts to my footer, still not working

```
<!-- Bootstrap-->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI Custom Download-->
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!-- Touch Punch-->
<script src="/js/touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

I know this question is getting old, but I did my damnedest to find a solution. It must be something simple that I am overlooking. If you can catch it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile was conflicting with jQuery UI. I swapped the order of the their script calls and downloaded a custom copy of jQuery Mobile that wouldn't conflict. Heads up for people using both: download custom versions right away. I wasted a lot of time and heartache messing with conflicting styling and JavaScript overrides. Two great libraries, but it took me a little while to realize that they are not fulling merged yet.